# Text Wrap:Splitting of String at new line(\n)

Tags: formula-field, string, data-types

I have following  Data type Order_Description__c (Long Text Area(32768) ).We are trying to wrap this data type at new line characer.

**Input Data:**

Long text area as a Order_Description__c field is:

EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS C3 Generic LOC 0833 Expected arrival 01/07/2016  OTYPE NE TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321

we tried on this direction :

Reading new line in SFDC  using '\r\n' (new line characters)

```
this.customobj.Order_Description__c
    = EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS + ' \r\n' +C3 Generic+' \r\n' + LOC 0833+' \r\n' + Expected arrival 01/07/2016+' \r\n' + OTYPE NE+' \r\n' + TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321;
```

This method has to work with when using an  with an sObject field.

**Expected Data :**
Using \n new line break iterator --  split into exact 6 lines

Like this :
EDI ORDER-SAVE COMMENTS

C3 Generic

LOC 0833

Expected arrival 01/07/2016

OTYPE NE

TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321

Any help on it would be much appreciated !

Comment: Please see edited question. there i have updated the tried section with exact data type.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Please let me know   if you need more information on it.

Comment: Here Line break as enter

Answer (score 2):

### Printing of new line character basically depends on the Datatype of the field.

> **Text Area / Long Text Area**  use "\r\n"
>
> **Rich Text Area** use   `<br/>`

---

```
Used <apex:outputField in both cases.
```